# S3 Policy for Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elb

I am struggling with the setting up an S3 policy to give access to Application Load Balancer to push logs.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1629585161607",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1629585158642",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::S3bucketname/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS":"arn:aws:iam:LoadBalancerId:root"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The `LoadBalancerId`came from the last part of the loan balancer's ARN; follows the trailing slash after the load balancer's name in the ARN.

The error got from S3 is `Invalid principal in policy`, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-logging-bucket-permissions) explain well what the policy should be exactly. Sadly, your policy is incorrect. It should follow the following format:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::elb-account-id:root"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/prefix/AWSLogs/your-aws-account-id/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/prefix/AWSLogs/your-aws-account-id/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
    }
  ]
}
```

On top of that, bucket must be in **same region** and be **encrypted**.

Comment: Can I ask, what is the `your-aws-account-id`? Where can I get this?

Comment: @Jim_Mcdonalds Check the docs. These are AWS's account numbers that you have to use. They are listed in the docs I linked.

Comment: so `The AWS account ID of the owner` is the IAM user that is setting up to policy?

Comment: Just check the docs. This is not IAM user. This is AWS account number (not yours).